# Does the Sport Loop have two lengths like the Sport Bands?

Tags: apple-watch, accessories

All of the individual Sport Bands come with both a small-to-medium and medium-to-large adjustable band. On the other hand, the Woven Nylon band does not and clearly says so on its Apple Store page:

> ### Band Size
>
> #### One Size
>
> Fits 125-195mm wrists.

<sup>38mm, not 42mm</sup>

The Sport Loop is less clear on whether it has two adjustable bands or one. Does anyone know whether is does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sport Loop is just a single band with no parts to be replaced/exchanged.

It works the same as the milanese loop.

[image: Apple Watch Sport Loop]